# Is it possible to run action on a child when parent is paused

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make the child node disappear while the parent is paused.

```
var plats: SKNode = SKNode();
var bigBox: SKSpriteNode!;

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    // Set anchor point
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    bigBox = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100));
    bigBox.zPosition = 1;

    plats.addChild(bigBox);

    var smallBox: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSizeMake(50, 50));
    smallBox.zPosition = 2;
    bigBox.addChild(smallBox);

    self.addChild(plats);
}
```

// Pause the plats when touch is detected and try to run the action on the child

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    // Here I pause the parent
    plats.paused = true;

    // Get the child node
    let smallBox: SKSpriteNode = bigBox.children[0] as! SKSpriteNode;

    println(smallBox);
    smallBox.paused = false;
    println(smallBox.paused); // return false but the action is never trigger

    // This part is never run, if I set plats.paused = false it will work but I dont that
    let scaleUp = SKAction.scaleTo(0.4, duration: 0.1);
    smallBox.runAction(scaleUp, completion: {
        self.bigBox.removeAllActions();
        self.bigBox.removeFromParent();
        println("done");
    });

}
```

Thats is all the code, you can paste and try to see that it dosent work

**xcode ver**: 6.3
**swift ver**: 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you pause a node, the node and all of its descendants are paused. In other words you cannot pause a parent node and one of its children keep going.